# Internal Server Error as response from Facebook Graph API on GET ads pagination

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

For a while now, we've been receiving a strange error response message **"Internal Server Error"** from the ads endpoint.

To keep it simple, we are working on an application that makes use of the **"Facebook Graph API"** which pulls the data at various levels from the Facebook interface to our database. While we were able to fetch the campaign level information, the issue right now is **"We are unable to fetch the Ad level information"**. It keeps throwing up an error "Internal Server error".

This issue in the past was confined to one particular account, but now, this is across all the accounts.

**Error Response**

```
response = (okhttp3.Response) Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Internal Server Error, url=https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/act_id/ads?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=%5B%22account_id%22%2C%22campaign_id%22%2C%22adset_id%22%2C%22id%22%2C%22bid_amount%22%2C%22
name%22%2C%22status%22%2C%22preview_shareable_link%22%5D&limit=25&
after=QVFIUkFzZAVdONXEwMXc5NjlOWURwczRQN0V3QW12NndRa0I4ZAUxsSjNkZA0FTRHR1U1dnaTQ5MTh2QnJ3bzNwWkNPd21jbC1tbjRmZAF81WVBsc0txaERCMHVn}
```

The code below worked fine for a couple of accounts earlier. However, the same, now gives the above-specified error message.

**Code to fetch Ad Information**

```
public List facebookAdsSynchThroughJson(String accessTokens, Long advertAccId, Properties googleStructureProperties, byte isOnScheduler, String appSecret) {
        this.access_tokens = accessTokens;
        this.appSecret = appSecret;
        APIContext context = new APIContext(accessTokens, appSecret).enableDebug(true);
        List<FacebookAdsStructure> adsList = new ArrayList<>();
        String ads = "";
        JSONObject advertIdObj = null;
        JSONArray dataList = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = null;
        boolean cond = true;
        boolean success = false;
        int limitValue = 100;
        try {
            while (cond) {
                try {
                    AdAccount adAccount = new AdAccount(advertAccId, context).get().execute();
                    List adsFields = new ArrayList();
                    adsFields.add("account_id");
                    adsFields.add("campaign_id");
                    adsFields.add("adset_id");
                    adsFields.add("id");
                    adsFields.add("bid_amount");
                    adsFields.add("name");
                    adsFields.add("status");
                    adsFields.add("preview_shareable_link");
                    Map<String, Object> adsmap = new HashMap<>();
                    adsmap.put("fields", adsFields);
                    adsmap.put("limit", limitValue);
                    ads = adAccount.getAds().setParams(adsmap).execute().getRawResponseAsJsonObject().toString();
                } catch (APIException ex) {
                    LOGGER.info("Exception thrown when fetching ads for Account Id: " + advertAccId + " with limit value: " + limitValue);
                    LOGGER.error(ex);
                    if (limitValue > 6) {
                        cond = true;
                        limitValue = limitValue / 2;
                    } else {
                        cond = false;
                        success = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!ads.isEmpty()) {
                    cond = false;
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            if (success) {
                advertIdObj = new JSONObject(ads);
                dataList = advertIdObj.getJSONArray("data");
                mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                adsList = mapper.readValue(dataList.toString(), new TypeReference<List<FacebookAdsStructure>>() {
                });
                JsonObject obj;
                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                JsonElement result = parser.parse(ads);
                obj = result.getAsJsonObject();
                int maxTries = 1;
                if (obj.has("data") && maxTries <= 5) {
                    while (obj.has("paging") && maxTries <= 5) {
                        JsonObject paging = obj.get("paging").getAsJsonObject();
                        if (paging.has("cursors")) {
                            JsonObject cursors = paging.get("cursors").getAsJsonObject();
                            String before = cursors.has("before") ? cursors.get("before").getAsString() : null;
                            String after = cursors.has("after") ? cursors.get("after").getAsString() : null;
                        }
                        String previous = paging.has("previous") ? paging.get("previous").getAsString() : null;
                        String next = paging.has("next") ? paging.get("next").getAsString() : "empty";
                        if (!next.equalsIgnoreCase("empty")) {
                            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                    .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                                    .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                                    .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                                    .build();
                            Request request1 = new Request.Builder().url(next).get().build();
                            Response response = client.newCall(request1).execute();
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                maxTries = 1;
                                ads = response.body().string();
                                advertIdObj = new JSONObject(ads);
                                dataList = advertIdObj.getJSONArray("data");
                                mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                                List<FacebookAdsStructure> adsLists = new ArrayList<>();
                                adsLists = mapper.readValue(dataList.toString(), new TypeReference<List<FacebookAdsStructure>>() {
                                });
                                adsList.addAll(adsLists);
                                LOGGER.info("Fetched the Ad Structure.." + adsList.size());
                                parser = new JsonParser();
                                result = parser.parse(ads);
                                obj = result.getAsJsonObject();
                            } else {
                                LOGGER.info("Exception in response when fetching ads for Account Id: " + advertAccId + " , error response message: " + response.message() + " and with limit value: " + limitValue);
                                maxTries++;
                                if (maxTries >= 6) {
                                    break;
                                }
                                try {
                                    LOGGER.info("Thread Sleeping For 2 Minutes - Started for fb se_account_id " + advertAccId + " and maxTries = " + maxTries);
                                    Thread.sleep(120000);
                                    LOGGER.info("Thread Sleeping For 2 Minutes - Completed for fb se_account_id " + advertAccId + " and maxTries = " + maxTries);
                                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(FacebookAccountStructureSyncThroughJson.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            obj = new JsonObject();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException | IOException | JSONException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex);
        }
        return adsList;
    }
```

Any assistance would be highly appreciated as this is turning out to be a real problem and the customer experience is at stake.

Comment: There’s already a bug report for a very similar issue, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/471423070078527/ Suggest you join that, or create your own, if your case is significantly different.

Comment: @04FS it has been a while since the facebook support team has updated the thread. It's a road blocker for us, hence posted it here so that someone could help me out.

Comment: Wouldn’t know _how_ to help you out here - we can not look into Facebook’s systems to get more information about the error. Unless someone would happen to come across this who experienced the same error and found a solution by chance …